# ¿Como puedo dividir y parsear convertido en un objeto un argumento pasado por process.argv en node?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, consola

Quería hacer un código sencillo de una calculadora, en donde yo le paso por consola un argumento al **código mediante process.argv[2]**, por ejemplo así: 46+775, o 14*2, o 7/4, etc. Operaciones matemáticas.
Pero **no encuentro la forma de poder tomar ese argumento en el código y realizar la operación, sin que importe cuantas cifras son a cada lado del operador matemático**. Se que podría hacerlo pasándole tres argumentos distintos, pero lo que quiero averiguar es como hacerlo pasándolo en un solo argumento tal que así: *node index.js* **5693*4** (ejemplo)

Desde ya muchas gracias!